# How to filter anonymous SIP messages / invites on Asterisk

Tags: c, asterisk, sip, pjsip

I have a CentOS 7 installation runnning Asterisk 14.0.3.6 with pjsip enabled and FreePBX for a UI. For a new project we will have many devices in the field which will want to be able to send a sip message without registering(in a separated network with their own router) to a registered SIP client in our environment (like a message receiver). After receiving the message we want to be able to initiate a call session if necessary.

The first challenge is to filter the sip messages / invites from sources I don't want to receive anything from. My plan is to register the devices in the database and match one or more values from a specific device to the incoming messages / invites and accept or decline these based on the existing values.

I'm a beginner to C and Asterisk, installing the environment is all experience I have so far. I do know how to code since I'm a C# programmer. Now I'm looking for the c file to edit so I can filter incoming invites or messages based on an array of values but I don't know which file and function is responsible for handling this.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk have built-in registrator. It will refuse messages from not-registered peers automaticaly.

Comment: hello, thank you for contributing to my question. Is this also the case when I enable 'Allow SIP Guests' and 'Allow Anonymous Inbound SIP Calls'?

Comment: When you allow anonimous calls you also can specify OTHER context for that. So you can write different rules.